# Fixando a posição do navegador em CSS

Tags: css3

Preciso que o dimensionamento da página não desloque o menu do projeto quando a página for dimensionada, pois quando mudo a dimensão da visualização ela se desloca individualmente do restante do corpo.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja que o menu e a imagem passam para a esquerda do projeto.
Estou aprendendo HTML5/CSS3 com esse tutorial, porém não consegui identificar o erro.

```css
nav#menu {
 display: block;
}

nav#menu ul {
 list-style: none;
 text-transform: none;
 position: absolute;
 left: 900px;
 top: -20px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Troquei a posição de absoluto para relativo, tanto no menu quanto na imagem, e depois posicionei da maneira que eu queria em top e left. Obrigado pela ajuda comunidade stackoverflowBR

```css
nav#menu {
 display: block;
}

nav#menu ul {
 list-style: none;
 text-transform: none;
 position: absolute;
 left: 900px;
 top: -20px;
```